# Running Eclipse on desktop = can't find companion library

Tags: eclipse

I just downloaded Eclipse Juno onto my machine. I extracted the files to an Eclipse subdirectory in "C:\Program Files". When I try to launch eclipse from here, it works great! But I don't want to have to navigate to this directory every time I want to launch eclipse. I tried just moving the executable to my Desktop, but then when I try to run it I get this message:

The eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion library.

How do I let eclipse know where it's companion library is if I don't plan to have them in the same folder? Please be very specific.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont move the executable to your desktop because the executable needs to be in the same directory with other files where it was. get it back and then make a shortcut or link to it. you are free to make the shortcut or link where you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well i had the same problem sometime back, and i figured out that since i've changed the location of my elcipse.exe , it has some how effected the "eclipse.ini " file

1.Path to -startup

D:\ < elcipse folder> elcipse:\ **plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar** \this is the start up jar file.

2.Path to shared lucher library

D:\ < elcipse folder> elcipse:\ **org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813** \this is the shared launcher library jar file.

just set the follwing two paths and ti will start up again like befor..
Happy coding..

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug filed with Eclipse for Windows and Mac:

When attempting to launch Eclipse (double click on Eclipse.app), the launch fails. The only action is a dialog box with this message:' the eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library'. I found an online description of the problem and the workaround here:

Specifically, as per the instructions above:

- I opened the Eclipse.app package, located eclipse.ini, edited it
- searched the plugins folder for something matching org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.carbon.
- copied the maching folder name (from plugins)
- pasted it as the terminating portion of the path for --launcher.library
- replaced the --launcher.library line with that path

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=288112

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Neon, 2017:

- I copied my old `.p2` folder found in my home.
- Ran eclipse again and it worked.

It used to be that you could just copy eclipse as a zip and it would work fine, but it seems some plugins now rely on the `.p2` folder.